# Change directory of remote machine through ssh after ~./bashrc execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, cd-command

I am trying to run a script on a remote machine via ssh. For this I want to change the directory and run the script from there. I found that the standard method on how to do this is:

```
ssh -Y -t user@server 'cd dir; exec bash'
```

However, the problem is that prior to running my script I need to setup some further scipts which I do in my ~./bashrc. My problem is that the way the command is written the change of directory happens before the ~./bashrc is even executed, i.e. messing up the code I need to set up before. Note: changing the command to

```
ssh -Y -t user@server 'exec bash; cd dir'
```

executes the bash normally, but doesn't change the directory afterwards. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about adding `cd dir` at the end of the `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Panki But I also want to run a script as a command which I dont want to run every time I open a new shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the way the command is written the change of directory happens before the ~./bashrc is even executed

It's more likely that `~/.bashrc` doesn't get read at all. Bash only reads `~/.bashrc` if it's invoked as an *interactive* (non-login) shell. When you give a command to run on the `ssh` command line, it executes the shell with the `-c` option, which makes it non-interactive.

But you can work around that by sourcing `.bashrc` manually:

```
ssh -t user@server '. ~/.bashrc; cd dir; exec bash'
```

Some `bashrc` files check if the shell is interactive, and only do changes if it is. <sub>(That sounds unnecessary, since `bashrc` is only read from an interactive shell, but because of the way Bash's startup files work, `bashrc` is also often sourced from `.bash_profile` or equivalent.)</sub>

To work around that, you'll need to force an interactive invocation of Bash, like so:

```
ssh -t user@server 'bash -ic "cd /tmp; exec bash"'
```

Manually sourcing `.bashrc` shouldn't be necessary now, since `-i` makes Bash do it itself. The *second* Bash (from `exec bash`) also does it, so if that's a problem, replace the last part with `exec bash --norc`.

...

It would probably be a good idea to split the relevant setup to a different file (say, `.thingy.rc`). Then source that from `.bashrc` (if necessary) and from the SSH command in stead of `.bashrc`.

Comment: You may need to invoke an interactive shell manually if bashrc checks for it.

Comment: @muru, hmm yes, that's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What about a [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) document, something like below:

```
ssh user@server << EOF exec bash       
cd dir
EOF
```

Comment: Does that do anything useful? The shell that starts gets the here-doc as its standard input, reads the `cd` command from it, and then exits when the here-doc ends.